# Issue in getting authentication URL in google drive V2

Tags: java, google-drive-api, uri, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I'm working with google drive authentication using OAuth2.0. Its working fine. As soon as the user clicks authenticate it opens a new tab in a browser for user permission. I'm not able to get the Url which it opens in new tab. I want to access my web application remotely. It doesn't work because the validation window opens in a default browser where application is running. Is there any way to get the complete Url?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;

public class GoolgeDriveUpload3 {

    private static String CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "yyyyyyyyyy";
    static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    static JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"),
            ".credentials/drive-java-quickstart");

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, jsonFactory,
                CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE)).setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                        .setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalCallbackServer()).authorize("user");
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, jsonFactory, credential).build();
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        Files.List request = null;
        request = service.files().list();
        FileList files = request.setQ("'root' in parents and trashed=false  ").execute();
        result.addAll(files.getItems());
        request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());

        for (File f : result) {
            System.out.println("Files are: " + f.getTitle() + " " + f.getId() + " " + f.getAlternateLink());
        }
    }
}


import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.VerificationCodeReceiver;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class LocalCallbackServer implements VerificationCodeReceiver {

    volatile String code;
    private final int LOCAL_SERVER_PORT = 9058;

    @Override
    public synchronized String waitForCode() {

        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        System.out.println("returning code is -> " + code);
        return code;

    }

    @Override
    public String getRedirectUri() {

        new Thread(new MyThread()).start();
        return "http://127.0.0.1:" + LOCAL_SERVER_PORT;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
    }

    class MyThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // return GoogleOAuthConstants.OOB_REDIRECT_URI;
                ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(LOCAL_SERVER_PORT);
                System.out.println("server is ready...");
                Socket socket = ss.accept();
                System.out.println("new request....");
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                String firstLine = null;

                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String read = br.readLine();
                firstLine = read;
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(os, true);

                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(firstLine, " ");
                st.nextToken();
                String codeLine = st.nextToken();
                st = new StringTokenizer(codeLine, "=");
                st.nextToken();
                code = st.nextToken();

                out.write("RETURNED CODE IS " + code + "");
                out.flush();
                // is.close();

                socket.close();

                System.out.println("Extracted coded is " + code);

                synchronized (LocalCallbackServer.this) {
                    LocalCallbackServer.this.notify();
                }
                System.out.println("return is " + sb.toString());

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LocalCallbackServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not a java dev so i cant be to much help.   The code you are using was probably designed to work with installed applications.   What you need is the code for web servers i think . Try digging around here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#web_server_applications

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check that